# MySQL - tell if column _all_ has same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query like

```
if (select count(*) from Users where fkId=5000 and status='r') =
   (select count(*) from Users where fkId=5000) then ..
```

in just *one* query.

What this means is, **if all the rows that have fkId=5000 *also* have `status=r`**, then do something.

There can be any number of rows with `fkId=5000`, and any fraction of those rows could have `status=r`, `status=k`, `status=l`, `status=a` etc.  I'm interested in the case where ALL the rows that have `fkId=5000` *also* have `status=r` (and not any other status).

The way I'm doing it now is

```
how many rows with id=5000 and status = 'r'?
how many rows with id=5000?
are those numbers equal? then ..
```

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite this query using only 1 query, instead of 2.  Keyword [ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html) didn't seem to be able to write such a query (`<> ALL` is equivalent to `NOT IN`).  I tried a couple of `GROUP BY` formulations but could not get the correct result to appear.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to do this is:

```
if not exists (select 1
               from users
               where fkid = 5000 and (status <> 'r' or status is null)
              )
```

This will stop the query at the first non-matching row.

Comment: I suppose I could enumerate all possible `status` values, but that makes the query too manual/tedious

Comment: @bobobobo . . . I don't understand your comment.  This is looking for status values that are not `r`, including `NULL`.

Comment: `status` can be _any letter_ of the alphabet, so this here query will succeed if _at least one row_ with `fkId=5000` has `r` status.  But I need to make it _only succeed_ if _all_ rows with `fkId=5000` _all_ have `r` status.

Comment: @bobobobo . . . I see what you are saying.  You want `not exists` rather than `exists`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check for any rows with status not equal to 'r'

```
     SELECT count(*)>0 FROM Users WHERE fkId = 5000 AND status != 'r'
```

Comment: reminds me of the pity that they dropped basic logic from bachelors cputer science at my university...\

Comment: @Uriil . . . This is not correct if `status` can have `NULL` values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, `status` can have many values, including `k` `l`, etc as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In the following case, if the number `1` is "true" (which it is) then you'll get `Yes` back, and if not you'll get `No` back:

```
SELECT IF(1, 'Yes', 'No') AS yesorno
```

(Go ahead -- try it!)

In your case however, the following would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT IF (
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE fkId=5000 AND status IN('r') AND status NOT IN('1', 'a', 'k')) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE fkId=5000),
   'They are equal.',
   'They are not equal.'
)
AS are_they_equal
```

By adding `AS`, you can manipulate the name of the "column" that's returned to you.

Hope that helps... Also, see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) if you'd like more info.

:)

Answer (score 0):

EASY!

Simply join back to the same table. Here is the complete code for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, fkID int NOT NULL,  status char(1), PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT Users (fkID, status) VALUES (5000, 'r');
INSERT Users (fkID, status) VALUES (5000, 'r');
INSERT Users (fkID, status) VALUES (5000, 'r');

-- The next query produces "0" to indicate no miss-matches
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users u1 LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u1.id=u2.id AND u2.status='r' WHERE u1.fkID=5000 AND u2.id IS NULL;

-- now change one record to create a miss-match
UPDATE Users SET status='l' WHERE id=3 ;

-- The next query produces "1" to indicate 1 miss-match
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users u1 LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u1.id=u2.id AND u2.status='r' WHERE u1.fkID=5000 AND u2.id IS NULL;

DROP TABLE Users;
```

So all you need to test for in the result is that it's 0 (zero) meaning everything has fkID=5000 also has status='r'

If you properly index your table then joining back to the same table is not an issue and certainly beats having to do a 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `NOT EXISTS` version - which should be the most efficient as it does no counting at all and exits as soon as it finds a value that doesn't match the conditions, there is one more way, that will work if `status` is not nullable and will be efficient if there is an index on `(fkId, status)`:

```
IF EXISTS 
   ( SELECT 1 
     FROM Users 
     WHERE fkId = 5000 
     HAVING MIN(status) = 'r' 
        AND MAX(status) = 'r'
   )
```

There is one difference though. The above will show false if there are no rows at all with `fkId=5000`, while the `NOT EXISTS` version will show true - which is probably what you want anyway.